# Dynamic style - manipulating CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image slider in a worpress theme that is currently using inline styles to change the display from block to none depending on which slide it is. Is there a way to separate this so that it will change dynamically in the js rather than using an inline style? It is changing to display block when it becomes the current slide.

html:

```
 <div class="single_fading_slide staged_slide" style="display: none;">
    <div class="positioning load_slide_image">
        <span id="355_img_1">
        <img src="http://imagehere" title="" alt="" width="960" height="340"            class="slide_image">
        </span>
    </div><!-- .positioning .slide_image -->
<div class="slide_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Script:I am new to js so any help is appreciated. I am sure not all of this applies but wanted to include it so you could see it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Add class nopreload to all images in 'slide_content' div
    if( jQuery('.slide_content').length>0 ) {
        jQuery('.slide_content').find('img').addClass('nopreload');
    }

            jQuery('#fading_slides').preloader({
            imgAppend: '.load_slide_image',
            fade: false,
            slider: true,
            onDone: function(){
                jQuery('#slider_module .mysite_preloader_large').remove();
                jQuery('.slider_nav').tabs('#fading_slides > div.single_fading_slide', {
                    effect: 'fade',
                    fadeInSpeed: 'fast',
                    rotate: true,
                    onBeforeClick : function(event,index) {
                        if(this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.vimeo_video').length>0) {
                            var vimeo_video = this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.vimeo_video').parent().html();
                            this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.vimeo_video').parent().empty().html(vimeo_video);
                            jQuery('.vimeo_video').each(function(index, vimeo_video){
                                Froogaloop.init([vimeo_video]);
                                vimeo_video.addEvent('onLoad', VimeoEmbed.vimeo_player_loaded);
                            });
                        }
                        if(this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.youtube_video').length>0) {
                            var vimeo_video = this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.youtube_video').parent().html();
                            this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.youtube_video').parent().empty().html(vimeo_video);
                            jQuery('.youtube_video').each(function(index, youtube_video){
                                onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(youtube_video.id);
                            });
                        }
                        _class = this.getPanes().eq(index).attr('class');
                        jQuery('#slider_module_inner').removeClass();
                        jQuery('#slider_module_inner').addClass( _class.replace('single_fading_slide ', '') );

                        if(this.getPanes().eq(index).children().eq(0).find('.vimeo_video').length>0 && typeof navScript != 'undefined'){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                jQuery('.slider_nav_thumb .slider_nav').animate({opacity:0},300);
                                jQuery('.slider_nav_thumb .slider_nav').animate({height:'0px'},300);
                              }, 1000 );
                        }
                    },
                    onClick : function(event,index) {}

                }).slideshow({clickable:false, autoplay:true, interval:4000, autopause:true});
                jQuery('#fading_slides').removeClass('noscript');
                jQuery('.slider_nav').removeClass('noscript');
            }
        });


});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery’s `.show()` and `.hide()` to handle this:

```
$('#selector').show();
$('#selector').hide();
```

I would highly recommend to spend some time reading the jQuery API documentation, I’m sure you’d be able to reduce the amount of code required a lot.